# AWS DynamoDB find Item by key in Map attribute (not Partition key)

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table in DynamoDB where I want to get an Item not by the partition key but by  a key in a Map attribute nested in the table.

```
{   
    "MyItem": { 
        "Key": "dfcwce",

        "NestedMap":
          {
          "map.key" : "value"
          "map.key2" : "value2"
          }
    }
}
```

I would like to query the item to get the Key of the item by the map.key.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can not query AWS Dynamodb without a Key field,
The Query operation finds items based on primary key values.
 
But you can query any table or secondary index that has a composite primary key (a partition key and a sort key).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html